# Finding a sum of random numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, sum

I have a column of 57 purchases and a column of 18 payments.  Is there a way to look up which purchases total a certain amount?  Example would be if I had purchases of $10, $15, and $1 in column A, and one of the payments was $26 in column B, it would be identified?

I've tried pivot tables and a variety of formulas and nothing has worked.

Comment: Can multiple sets of purchases sum to a given target amount?  In any event, if your goal is to go from the number 26 to the three numbers 10, 15, 1, then you are dealing with a nontrivial subset sum problem. VBA (or maybe the solver) would be required.

Comment: I don't see anything `random` in your problem description. Can you explain/justify why that tag is appropriate?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Excel or Google Sheets to identify which purchases in your column total a certain amount. One way to do this is by using formulas like SUMIF, SUMIFS, or combinations of functions like VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Here's a basic example:

Let's assume:

Column A contains your purchases.
Column B contains your payments.

You want to find out which combination of purchases in Column A totals a specific amount, say $26 (which is in one of your payments in Column B).

In this case, you can use a formula in a separate cell to check for combinations:

Using SUMIF/SUMIFS:

You could use SUMIF or SUMIFS to check combinations of purchases that sum up to your target amount.

=SUMIF(range_of_purchases, "<=" & target_amount, range_of_purchases)

For example:

=SUMIF(A:A, "<=" & $B$1, A:A)

Where $B$1 contains the amount you're looking to match ($26 in this case), and A:A is your list of purchases.

You can adjust this formula based on your specific setup and requirements.

Using VLOOKUP/INDEX MATCH:

You could use these functions along with other helper columns or arrays to identify the combination of purchases that sum up to your target amount.

For instance:

=INDEX(range_of_purchases, MATCH(target_amount, range_of_possible_sums, 0))

Comment: Since the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is known to be NP-hard, I'm skeptical that it can be solved in Excel using spreadsheet functions. Perhaps you could elaborate on your `INDEX` and `MATCH` idea. For example, what is `range_of_possible_sums` and how does one obtain it?